# INDEX/MATCH Unique Return Values

Tags: excel, indexing, match

I'm having a problem. I have an excel workbook with 2 sheets in it. Sheet 1 has a list of addresses with ID numbers. Sheet 2 has a significantly smaller list with no id numbers. Some of the addresses on Sheet 2 appear on Sheet 1. I need to get the appropriate ID numbers from Sheet 1, and apply them to the addresses on Sheet 2, but only for the addresses that appear in both lists.

Comment: So use match() with the last argument as false.

Comment: ^^^ wrapped in IFERROR to return blanks for missing items